# Using .MEASURE on DC sweeps in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, dc-sweep

How can I `.MEASURE` at what input voltage a certain current occurs when doing a DC sweep in LTSpice?

For instance, consider the following situation:

[image]

I was hoping to find the voltage that generates a base current of \$200\mu\text{A}\$ by using `FIND ... WHEN` as shown in the image, but I only get `Measurement "ub" FAIL'ed`. (I guess the syntax is not applicable to DC sweeps?)

Comment: Why can't you just plot Vbe against Ib instead and look at the resulting graph?

Comment: `Ib(Q1)` never gets to be `200u` given your setup; try `20u`. You could have found this out for yourself if you had actually plotted the waveforms.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command to measure it when you eventually get it to 200uA.

[image]

Another variation with respect to the sweep variable:

[image]